# Why multiple task is not coming in my drools application?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, drools

I am trying to make a drools application which is based on spring mvc and hibernate.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.drools.task");   
Environment env = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newEnvironment();
env.set(EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, emf);
TaskService taskService = new TaskService(emf, systemEventListener);

TaskServiceSession taskSession = taskService.createSession();
taskSession.addUser(new User("Administrator"));
taskSession.addUser(new User("Myuser"));// can be set to logged in user at runtime

MinaTaskServer server = new MinaTaskServer(taskService);
Thread thread = new Thread(server);
thread.start();

ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Log",humanTaskHandler);
ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", wsHumanTaskHandler);

 KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(ksession, "test");
// start a new process instance
ksession.startProcess("HumanTaskSample");
```

What does `createEntityManagerFactory` does? 
Does it drop all my tables from the db and create a new one every time?

Because in my task table , everytime it contains only one rows?

Why??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `persistence.xml` file in your project, that contains line

```
<persistence-unit name="org.drools.task">
```

your table are drpped becouse you have next proprty in you `persistence.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

`create-drop` means: drop the schema at the end of the session

Change value to `validate` or `update`